# Let f be continuous on [a,b] Show that there is a ξ ∈ [a,b]

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

There exists a ξ such that $\textstyle \int$  $f(x)dx = f(ξ)(b − a)$.

Let  $f (x) := 2x^2 − 5x − 6$  and [a, b] := [−1, 3] How do I determine ξ?

Comment: Have you tried computing what value $f( \xi)$ must be???

Comment: The average value theorem! Hint: Solve the equation - integrate and solve the resulting equation!

Comment: It will be an equation to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: Write $\chi = \int_{-1}^3 f(x) dx $. Then $\chi = 4f(\xi) $ so
$$ 2\xi^2-5\xi-6 = \frac{\chi}{4}. $$
So you'll be solving the quadratic $2\xi^2-5\xi-6 - \frac{\chi}{4}=0$ for $\xi$.